# just downloaded fineuploader am I missing something?

Tags: fine-uploader

I just downloaded fineuploader and i'm not really sure where to go next. The download came with no documentation at all, just a weird html template that doesn't really make much sense to me.

The fineuploader website has no documentation from what I can see, there are links to pages on how to style up the plugin but the links go nowhere. All there are is a few examples, one of which make sense since they seem to reference missing information.

On your website you have these instructions

You can quickly set up an HTML page in order to use Fine Uploader:

```
Download and unpack the latest version of Fine Uploader.
Use one of the provided server scripts, or write your own.
Setup your HTML and javascript.
Upload!
```

But I see no "provided server scripts" or any instructions on what to do with the js and css files I have downloaded.

Are you please able to clarify?

Comment: Sorry, it seems as if our documentation server broke within the last few hours or so.  We are looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry about that, some invalid syntax in one of the markdown files in our documentation caused the re-rendering of the docs site to fail after a push earlier in the day.  I've corrected the error, and the documentation is back up at http://docs.fineuploader.com.

We will make it a priority tomorrow to ensure this does not happen again.  At the very least, we need to adjust our alert system to be sure we know when rendering fails like this right away, but there are other prudent changes to be made as well.

Again, my apologies.